# GLIBCXX_3.4.26 not found running cross-complied program on BeagleBone

Tags: c++, linux, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //ostringstream s;
    cout << "cpp test" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I build it on Ububtu 20.04 desktop using cross-compiler:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/cpp_test.d" -MT"src/cpp_test.o" -o "src/cpp_test.o" "../src/cpp_test.cpp"
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  -o "cpp_test"  ./src/cpp_test.o
```

Then I copy `cpp_test` to BeagleBone Black Wireless board and execute it:

```
debian@beaglebone:~/c$ ./cpp_test 
cpp test
debian@beaglebone:~/c$ ldd cpp_test
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0xbee85000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6ea1000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6e78000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6d7e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6d03000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6fbe000)
```

Now I uncomment the line `ostringstream s;`, build the program, copy it to BeagleBone and execute:

```
debian@beaglebone:~/c$ ./cpp_test 
./cpp_test: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./cpp_test)
debian@beaglebone:~/c$ ldd cpp_test
./cpp_test: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./cpp_test)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0xbefa6000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6e22000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6d28000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f3f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6cad000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6c84000)
```

Additional information from the board:

```
debian@beaglebone:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf$ ls -l | grep libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       19 Apr  6  2019 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.25
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1019772 Apr  6  2019 libstdc++.so.6.0.25
debian@beaglebone:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf$ uname -r
4.19.94-ti-r45
debian@beaglebone:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf$ uname -a
Linux beaglebone 4.19.94-ti-r45 #1buster SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 18 19:18:41 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ strings /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.25 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
...
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
```

Additional information from the host:

```
alex@alex-u20:~$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/9/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --without-target-system-zlib --enable-libpth-m2 --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-multilib --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu1)

alex@alex-u20:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
...
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
```

Finally, this program runs on the desktop using qemu:

```
alex@alex-u20:~/tmp/cpp_test/Debug$ qemu-arm-static -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ cpp_test
cpp test
```

Both computers, host and BB board, are completely updated.

Comment: Suggests you're using the wrong toolchain maybe? Check your GCC version...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: the answer updated, see `Additional information from the host`

Comment: What's the version of Ubuntu on the BeagleBone?

Comment: `libstdc++.so.6.0.25` vs `GLIBCXX_3.4.26`?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: `Linux beaglebone 4.19.94-ti-r45 #1buster SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 18 19:18:41 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: Seems to be working with Linaro toolchain.

Comment: @AlexF The version of Ubuntu, not of Linux

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Debian from here: https://beagleboard.org/latest-images Don't remember exact version, I downloaded it about 1 month ago.

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-check-your-ubuntu-version/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really an answer, but on my Ubuntu 20.04 system, I have package libstdc++6 installed, containing libstdc++.so.6.0.28.

Looking for symbols

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28 | grep GLIBCXX
```

gives

> ...
> GLIBCXX_3.4.19
> GLIBCXX_3.4.20
> GLIBCXX_3.4.21
> GLIBCXX_3.4.22
> GLIBCXX_3.4.23
> GLIBCXX_3.4.24
> GLIBCXX_3.4.25
> GLIBCXX_3.4.26
> GLIBCXX_3.4.27
> GLIBCXX_3.4.28
> ...

So, it seems, version 6.0.28 corresponds to symbol 3.4.28.

In your case, you have libstdc++.so.6.0.**25** installed, which is just one less than GLIBCXX_3.4.**26**.
So, you must either upgrade the Beagle board, or downgrade the dev environment.

---

Current (focal, 20.04) libstdc++6 version is 6.0.28. Version 6.0.25 is contained in bionic (18.04), which also contains gcc-8.

So, maybe installing package gcc-8/g++-8 and its dependencies (e.g. libstdc++-8-dev) solves this.

Comment: Thanks, the reason is correct. The simplest solution I have for now is to switch to Linaro toolchain.

Comment: @AlexF Another solution could be to create a docker container with Ubuntu 18.04 or the corresponding Debian release.

Answer (score 22):

`GLIBCXX_3.4.26` comes with `gcc-8`. Installing gcc-8 and upgrading `libstdc++6` worked for me. Run the following as shown [here](https://github.com/ufo-project/ufochain/issues/3):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wget gcc-8 unzip libssl1.0.0 software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libstdc++6
```

Comment: Is there any way to get an updated `libstdc++.so.6` for armv7l without use `apt` (to a Yocto project based distro) ? I already have gcc-9 in my host computer (Ubuntu WSL x86_64)  however in my target (armv7l )  I had an outdated version of `libstdc++.so.6`

Answer (score 0):

You may not have Debian 11 as OS, 3.4.26 is not available for Debian 10. After upgrading to Debian 10, I could run the program without error.

Comment: You mean after "upgrading to Debian 11", right?

Comment: i don't remember, sorry @MarkJin