# /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found

Tags: linux, tensorflow, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

i need help to install tensorflow on jetson nano.
I follow guide at: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html

- After that, my tensorflow version is: 1.15.5+nv22.3
- But when i run:

> > > import tensorflow

- This error show up: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found
- Pls help me because i have tried so many ways but libstdc dont update glibcxx_3.4.26
- Versions:

- python: 3.8.0
- jetpack: # R32 (release), REVISION: 7.2, GCID: 30192233, BOARD: t210ref, EABI: aarch64, DATE: Wed Apr 20 21:34:48 UTC 2022

Maybe i installed wrong version of TF ?? I tried other versions but only jetpack 5.0 installs successfully

Comment: Could you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63190229/glibcxx-3-4-26-not-found-running-cross-complied-program-on-beaglebone

Comment: I tried to install libstdc++-8-dev but it didn't work

Comment: But now when i 'import tensorflow', it return Segmentation fault (core dumped) =))))